# Installing maven archetypes overwrites old versions

Tags: maven, maven-2, maven-archetype

I am trying to install an archetype in my local repository but when updating the version and generating an application based on the archetype, it does not give me to choose the previous versions, this forces me to always use the last one installed.

This is the pom of my project with the archetype:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <groupId>com.foo</groupId>
  <artifactId>foo</artifactId>
  <version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <packaging>maven-archetype</packaging>

  <name>foo</name>

  <build>
    <extensions>
      <extension>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.archetype</groupId>
        <artifactId>archetype-packaging</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.0</version>
      </extension>
    </extensions>

    <pluginManagement>
      <plugins>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-archetype-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.2.0</version>
        </plugin>
      </plugins>
    </pluginManagement>
  </build>
</project>
```

I just run an mvn install and it generates an archetype-catalog file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<archetype-catalog xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-archetype-plugin/archetype-catalog/1.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/archetype-catalog-1.0.0.xsd"
    xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-archetype-plugin/archetype-catalog/1.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <archetypes>
    <archetype>
      <groupId>com.foo</groupId>
      <artifactId>foo</artifactId>
      <version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
      <description>foo</description>
    </archetype>
  </archetypes>
</archetype-catalog>
```

If I increase the version to 1.0.1-SNAPSHOT and run the mvn install command again, only the latest version appears in the archetype-catalog:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<archetype-catalog xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-archetype-plugin/archetype-catalog/1.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/archetype-catalog-1.0.0.xsd"
    xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-archetype-plugin/archetype-catalog/1.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <archetypes>
    <archetype>
      <groupId>com.foo</groupId>
      <artifactId>foo</artifactId>
      <version>1.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
      <description>foo</description>
    </archetype>
  </archetypes>
</archetype-catalog>
```

If I check the metadata file of the archetype in my .m2 if both versions come out:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<metadata>
  <groupId>com.foo</groupId>
  <artifactId>foo</artifactId>
  <versioning>
    <versions>
      <version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
      <version>1.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </versions>
    <lastUpdated>20201028190227</lastUpdated>
  </versioning>
</metadata>
```

If I try to generate an application using the archetype with the command mvn archetype: generate -Dfilter = foo, I get an option to select but it passes me to the variable configuration, I cannot select the previous versions:

```
mvn archetype:generate -Dfilter=foo
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO]
[INFO] ----------------------------< com.foo:foo >-----------------------------
[INFO] Building foo 1.0.1-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] --------------------------[ maven-archetype ]---------------------------
[INFO]
[INFO] >>> maven-archetype-plugin:3.2.0:generate (default-cli) > generate-sources @ foo >>>
[INFO]
[INFO] <<< maven-archetype-plugin:3.2.0:generate (default-cli) < generate-sources @ foo <<<
[INFO]
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-archetype-plugin:3.2.0:generate (default-cli) @ foo ---
[INFO] Generating project in Interactive mode
[INFO] No archetype defined. Using maven-archetype-quickstart (org.apache.maven.archetypes:maven-archetype-quickstart:1.0)
Choose archetype:
1: local -> com.foo:foo (foo)
Choose a number or apply filter (format: [groupId:]artifactId, case sensitive contains): : 1
Define value for property 'groupId':
```

I want to be able to select previous versions of my archetype, I know it can be done because I have already done it but I cannot find the reason why when installing a new version the previous ones no longer appear. Any ideas?

**Solution:**

I have solved the problem by running these commands after installing the archetype (it didn't happen to me before, it updated automatically):

```
mvn archetype:update-local-catalog
mvn archetype:crawl
```